# Using Correlation Sets in Intalio?

Tags: process, correlation, business-process-management, bpmn

I have the Screensot shown below. I need to know how many Correlations are used and which elements belong to what Correlation. And I need to describe what was correlated. I understand correlation but not in this example in Intalio. I need it as a preparation for an University exam.

[image]

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Outline pane , you can see an downward arrow, Click on that and it will show 2 options , "Templates" and "Correation". Select Correlation option .

When you will select 'Correlation' option then it will show the executable  pool in which correlation is defind. Expand that and you will see the correlation Name.

Right click on Correlation Name and select Edit option and it will take you to the 'CorrelationSet Definition" window. There you can see the variables. The variables which are marked checked are the one used for correlation.

I hope it helps you.

Thanks,
Sumit Taneja